# This nasty button is double jumping

Tags: javascript, html

A button is appended as a child to each slide by javascript for an important undisclosable reason. What it does it is it scrolls to the next slide:

```
<slide id="slide1" class="slide">
</slide>
<slide id="slide2" class="slide">
</slide>
<slide id="slide3" class="slide">
</slide>
<slide id="slide4" class="slide">
</slide>
<slide id="slide5" class="slide">
</slide>
<slide id="slide6" class="slide">
</slide>
<slide id="slide7" class="slide">
</slide>
```

And this is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
for(i=1;i<7;i++){
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.id=i;
    li.className="dav";
    li.innerHTML="^";
    li.onclick=scrolls;
    document.getElementById("slide"+i).appendChild(li);
}
function scrolls(){
    var a=++this.id;
    document.getElementById("slide"+a).scrollIntoView();
}
</script>
```

And this is the question the buttons work well for the first time but it in the next click it jumps two slides ahead, eg: after clicking the first button and scrolling up and clicking it again the view is on to the third slide not the second one any more. What is happening any help would be appreciated and also PLEASE GET THIS NASTY BUG OF ME! LASTLY DON'T USE JQUERY

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have incremented `++this.id`. Try `this.id+1`, because I'm fairly sure you don't want to *modify* the `id`, just get it and add one.

It's also worth noting that `this.id` is not something you should toy with lightly. Try something like `this.setAttribute("data-target",'slide'+(i+1));` when setting it, then `document.getElementById(this.getAttribute("data-target")).scrollIntoView();` - magic! :D